# Internet Explorer Displays Time with Milliseconds as Nan

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I could not find any solutions in web, so I am posting this

**My Problem :**

I am displaying **Date** and **Time** from database, it is being displayed correctly in `Chrome` browser but time is not displayed in `Internet Explorer` (it is displayed as 09/19/2016 NaN:NaN:NaN AM)

what I have tried

**My Code Snippet :**

```
function ParseTime(date) {
        var t = date.toString();
        t = new Date(t.replace('T', ' '));
        var Tdata = new Date(t);
        var format = "AM";
        var hour = Tdata.getHours();
        var min = Tdata.getMinutes();
        var sec = Tdata.getSeconds();
        if (hour > 11) { format = "PM"; }
        if (hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
        if (hour == 0) { hour = 12; }
        if (min < 10) { min = "0" + min; }
        if (hour < 10) { hour = "0" + hour; }
        if (sec < 10) { sec = "0" + sec; }
        var Time = " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + format;
        return Time;
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: really I tried it on IE it works. anyway what's the date string did you passed?

Comment: this is my date String passed in function parameter "2016-01-02T22:54:09.12"

Answer (score 0):

how are you invoking your function? Even if you are invoking it with with

```
ParseTime(new Date('2016-09-22T08:43:23'))
```

toString will convert it to something else.

So check what t contains after

```
var t = date.toString();
```

if it contains, for example

```
Thu Sep 22 2016 08:43:23 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

you will get

```
hu Sep 22 2016 08:43:23 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

the date parsing implementations are different for each browser so Chrome survives this malformed string and IE doesn't

Answer (score 0):

In that case if you want to convert time to a format just use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Its good for manipulating dates in JS. They have many functions that can be useful. You can also format to any requited format and create date object in any format.

#### Syntax

```
moment().format('YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss');
```

Comment: which means I need to first format with moment.js and then have to get the time is it so?

Comment: no you don't need no more that function you create because moment JS can do it alone

Comment: is there any thing I can do with out moment.js ?

Comment: @MBalajivaishnav try removing this code t = new Date(t.replace('T', ' '));

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked, can you please make it as a answer so that I can accept it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123907/discussion-between-m-balajivaishnav-and-newbee-dev).

Comment: the date and time displayed in chrome is differs from the date and time displayed in IE

Comment: yey, to solve that just restore t = new Date(t.replace('T', ' '));

Comment: to solve the IE bug just condition if (isEI() == false) {
        t = new Date(t.replace('T', ' '));
    } which mean if your using IE you will not going to remove the T from the string

Answer (score 0):

Just don't remove the "T" string if browser is IE just make sure you have also jquery in your html

```
function ParseTime(date) {
    var t = date.toString();
    if (isIE() == false) {
        t = new Date(t.replace('T', ' '));
    }
    var Tdata = new Date(t);
    var format = "AM";
    var hour = Tdata.getHours();
    var min = Tdata.getMinutes();
    var sec = Tdata.getSeconds();
    if (hour > 11) { format = "PM"; }
    if (hour > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
    if (hour == 0) { hour = 12; }
    if (min < 10) { min = "0" + min; }
    if (hour < 10) { hour = "0" + hour; }
    if (sec < 10) { sec = "0" + sec; }
    var Time = " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " " + format;
    return Time;
}

function isIE() {    

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || navigator.userAgent.match(/rv 11/)) || $.browser.msie == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```